# ADODB.Connection over LAN network very slow > more speed needed

Tags: ms-access, networking, ado

I am using an ADODB.Connection object with "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=test.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=test;Persist Security Info=False;".

The speed of db_obj.Open(db_conn_string) is very different.

- local: 0.05 sec
- over LAN network: 1 - 1.5 sec

After that i am using a select statement.

I testet every line per speedcheck. My only slow down is the open command.

**Any ideas how to increase speed over network?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiousity, why are you so worried about the difference between mere seconds in connection speed?

Is the issue that you are creating these connections and dropping them constantly throughout your code, therefore the extra second or so adds up to several minutes?

If so, your goal might need to be refining your connection usage itself. Instead of constantly dropping the connection, maybe just keep it active.

Also, on a side note, you may want to rethink keeping the password saved in the connection string (assuming this is not just personal use or whatever).

Those things aside, your method of connection is about as good as it gets from a single shot perspective.

There are some other options, such as opening the connection as a recordset, but the speed would not see any significant increase on the opening side.

```
Dim rs1 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConn As String
Dim sSQL As String

FilePath = "[File Location]"
sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;Data source=" & _
     FilePath & "\[DatabaseName].[Extension]"

conn.Open sConn
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1"
rs1.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs1.Open sSQL, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic 'lock depending on user requirements

rs1.MoveFirst
Do While rs1.EOF = False
    'Code here
    rs1.MoveNext
Loop

'For additional manipulation
rs1.MoveFirst
Do While rs1.EOF = False
    'Code here
    rs1.MoveNext
Loop

rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing
```

To the best of my knowledge, other than that, your only real solution would be to increase the speed of the physical network itself (if plausible).

Comment: I am using it for right-management, so users are blocked until the check is done. If there is nothing faster than opening a connection this way, you are right, it's only depending on LAN-speed.